# Unable to access tableau data using REST API via python when we have multiple dashboards in a a worksheet

Tags: python, tableau-api

I am basically trying to access tableau underline data via rest API using python.
I am able to do so when we have one dashboard (chart) in the worksheet. However, when we have multiple dashboards in one worksheet it's only returning the data for first dashboard in the worksheet.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what your question is.

But each view/sheet in the dashboard has a different ID.

You need to specific which one you would like to see. You can get the different IDs using a GET request.

The first dashboard is the default one. This may be the source of your error and why you are only getting the first one returned.